# Post-commit not firing

Tags: svn

My very basic post-commit script will not fire. However, I have no problem with my pre-commit script.

First, the rights on those files

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 3426 Jul 23 09:02 pre-commit
-rw-r--r-- 1 apache apache 2106 Jul 23 08:38 post-commit
```

`Pre-commit` file content:

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
exit 2
```

Error caught

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 255) with no output.
svn: MERGE of '/post-commit-tests/trunk': 409 Conflict (http://mydomain.com)
```

`Post-commit` file content

```
REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
exit 2
```

No errors are thrown or caught.

I'm checking/committing out the code via http in Eclipse.

**Update #1**

post-commit was run after having the pre-commit script disabled (renamed back to .tmpl).

Should an exit code in the post-commit be acknowledged by the client?

**Update #2**

New permissions:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 apache apache 2114 Jul 23 10:19 post-commit
```

Here is the entire file of the post-commit

```
# !/bin/bash

# POST-COMMIT HOOK
#
# The post-commit hook is invoked after a commit.  Subversion runs
# this hook by invoking a program (script, executable, binary, etc.)
# named 'post-commit' (for which this file is a template) with the 
# following ordered arguments:
#
#   [1] REPOS-PATH   (the path to this repository)
#   [2] REV          (the number of the revision just committed)
#
# The default working directory for the invocation is undefined, so
# the program should set one explicitly if it cares.
#
# Because the commit has already completed and cannot be undone,
# the exit code of the hook program is ignored.  The hook program
# can use the 'svnlook' utility to help it examine the
# newly-committed tree.
#
# On a Unix system, the normal procedure is to have 'post-commit'
# invoke other programs to do the real work, though it may do the
# work itself too.
#
# Note that 'post-commit' must be executable by the user(s) who will
# invoke it (typically the user httpd runs as), and that user must
# have filesystem-level permission to access the repository.
#
# On a Windows system, you should name the hook program
# 'post-commit.bat' or 'post-commit.exe',
# but the basic idea is the same.
# 
# The hook program typically does not inherit the environment of
# its parent process.  For example, a common problem is for the
# PATH environment variable to not be set to its usual value, so
# that subprograms fail to launch unless invoked via absolute path.
# If you're having unexpected problems with a hook program, the
# culprit may be unusual (or missing) environment variables.
# 
# Here is an example hook script, for a Unix /bin/sh interpreter.
# For more examples and pre-written hooks, see those in
# the Subversion repository at
# http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/tools/hook-scripts/ and
# http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/hook-scripts/


REPOS="$1"
REV="$2"
echo "my message" 1>&2
exit 2
```

When I commit, it's still going through without coming back with an error in Eclipse. However, running ./post-commit will output as expected.

**Update #3**

SVN: 1.6
Apache: 2.2
Using DAV

Comment: You should post the real content of the files if you want us to help. The pre-commit you posted is much shorter than what is shown by your `ls` output.

Comment: @Matteo I skipped displaying the comments. Everything else is there.

Comment: You have almost 3KB of comments for 27 characters of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all due to a permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the scripts executable: `chmod +x pre-commit post-commit`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

**Exit code**

A pre-commit hook is used to perform checks before the commit. From the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit):

> If the `pre-commit` hook program returns a nonzero exit value, the commit is aborted, the commit transaction is removed, and anything printed to *stderr* is marshalled back to the client.

You finish you pre-commit with

```
exit 2
```

which will always tell Subversion to abort the commit. Since there will be no commit, the post-commit hook will never be executed.

**Permissions**

In addition both scripts should be executable:

```
chmod +x pre-commit post-commit
```

`-rw-r--r--` means that they can be read (and written by the owner) but not executed.

**Shebang**

Your script is missing a [Shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) at the beginning specifying which interpreter should be called. E.g.,

```
#!/bin/sh
```

**Update 1**

The answer to your update is also in the [documentation](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.ref.reposhooks.post-commit):

> If the post-commit hook returns a nonzero exit status, the commit will not be aborted since it has already completed. However, anything that the hook printed to stderr will be marshalled back to the client, making it easier to diagnose hook failures.

The code will not be sent to the client but everything you put on standard error will. For example:

```
echo "my message" 1>&2
```

**Update 2**

You are still missing a `#` at the beginning of the Shebang but I assume it's a copy&paste issue.

As specified in the documentation having an `exit 2` will **not** cause an abortion of the commit. It will go through (if you want to block a commit you will have to do it in the `pre-commit` hook). As you are **not** returning anything on standard error nothing will be displayed by the client. (see the content of my answer to your first update)

Add something like

```
echo "Error! Something went wrong after your commit!" 1>&2
```

to your `post-commit` script

Comment: pre-commit was disabled when testing post-commit.

Comment: Then you should have said so. With exit 2 as you specified the post-commit will never be fired.

Comment: Did you also fix the permissions? Did you also fix the Shebang? Did you test if the script runs? `./post-commit`

Comment: permissions fixed, Shebang fixed and the script runs and echoes the content through Putty... however, I'm not seeing the echo in my svn client (Eclipse).

Comment: I added SVN specific commands in my post-commit and they run fine doing ./post-commit. However, through my Eclipse client, none of these run?

Comment: Check with a command line client. There are many known issues with Eclipse not showing post-commit errors.

Comment: I'm thinking it's a permission issue and looking into it. I did try to connect with a command line client but got another type of error that I'm also looking into.

Answer (score 0):

`post-commit` will never fire if pre-commit returns an error condition.

Comment: pre-commit was disabled when testing post-commit.